# Python - How to combine two pdf pages into a single page

Tags: python, pdf

I am generating a series of plots using matplotlib. Each plot is for a different location, so the data within the plot will change.

I also have a pdf template that I would like to use to paste the plots within. This template is more complicated than I would want to replicate in matplotlib.

I have set the transparency to True, so I'm hoping that it will merge nicely without covering up parts of the template.

What I was trying was to first export the matplotlib plot as a pdf then use PyPDF2 to merge the two pdf's together, but that doesn't seem to work as I just wind up with two separate pages, which duh... but I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
plt.savefig("testhole.pdf", transparent=True)
#Merge pdf's
path = r'C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\xxx'
template_path = path + r'\Template.pdf'
testhole_file = path + r'\testhole.pdf'
test_hole_path = path + r'\\' + location + r'.pdf'
pdf_template = PdfFileReader(template_path)
pdf_testhole = PdfFileReader(testhole_file)
pdf_merger = PdfFileMerger()
pdf_merger.append(pdf_template)
pdf_merger.append(pdf_testhole)
with open(test_hole_path, 'wb') as fileobj:
    pdf_merger.write(fileobj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Flavio, I haven't tried your answer but I was able to get it to work. The basic idea is like adding a watermark:

```
#sns.lineplot(x=sieves, y=percent_finer, ax=ax)
plt.savefig("testhole.pdf", transparent=True)

#Merge pdf's
path = r'C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\xxx'
template_path = path + r'\Template.pdf'
testhole_file = path + r'\testhole.pdf'
test_hole_path = path + r'\\' + location + r'.pdf'
pdf_template = PdfFileReader(template_path).getPage(0)
pdf_testhole = PdfFileReader(testhole_file)
pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

#Merge pages together
for page in range(pdf_testhole.getNumPages()):
    page = pdf_testhole.getPage(page)
    page.mergePage(pdf_template)
    pdf_writer.addPage(page)

with open(test_hole_path,'wb') as fileobj:
    pdf_writer.write(fileobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

since append requires a `fileobj` to be passed I think you have to use:

```
pdf_template = PdfFileReader(open(template_path, 'rb'))
pdf_testhole = PdfFileReader(open(testhole_file, 'rb'))
```

Please, let me know if this solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with PyPDF2 adding a stamp to one or a series of pages, switched to [pdfrw](https://pypi.org/project/pdfrw/) and solved my requirements.

```
def add_stamp_to_pdf(form_pdf, overlay_pdf, output):

    form = pdfrw.PdfReader(form_pdf)
    olay = pdfrw.PdfReader(overlay_pdf)
    
    for form_page, overlay_page in zip(form.pages, olay.pages):
        merge_obj = pdfrw.PageMerge()
        overlay = merge_obj.add(overlay_page)[0]
        pdfrw.PageMerge(form_page).add(overlay).render()
        
    writer = pdfrw.PdfWriter()
    writer.write(output, form)
```

There is also a very good Post from Mike Driscoll https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/06/06/creating-and-manipulating-pdfs-with-pdfrw/